# Escaping html / javascript: Appending content of db field into DOM with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, escaping

I want to do the following within rails. In a textfield of my db, there is the following html / javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  document.write('<div id="test"></div>');
</script>
```

I want to append the contents of this field into the head-tag of the DOM, so the inserted js will be executed.

In my rails erb-view, I have the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var code = "<%= @ticket.code %>"; // Content of codesnippet above
  $('head').append(code);
</script>
```

However I get some the following rendered output of the view:

```
var code = "&lt;script type=&quot;text/javascript&quot;&gt;
  document.write('&lt;div id=&quot;test&quot;&gt;&lt;/div&gt;');
&lt;/script&gt;";
```

Error message:
**unterminated string literal**

I tried to gsub linebreaks and other ways of escaping, but I've got no clue, what actually is the best way to escape it. How can I get it correclty escaped and inserted into the DOM?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe rails 3 comes with JQuery so why not just use:

```
$(document).onload(function()
{ 
    document.write('<div id="test"></div>');
});
```

and I believe on var code you should do the following:

```
var code = "<%= escape_javascript(@ticket.code.html_safe) %>"
```

Comment: using html_safe is producing another problem:

var code = "<script type="text/javascript">
document.write('<div id="test"></div>');
</script>";

The quotation marks now make the variable declaration end too soon.

Comment: @agieche then try ```var code = "<%= escape_javascript(@ticket.code.html_safe) %>"```

Comment: Yeah, this worked smoothly. Thanks! Please edit your answer, so I can mark it as correct.